# NodeJS/Express proper handle of React builds

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, caching, static

I would like to know how to properly handle React builds in a Express app. One major issue that I'm having right now is that, when using a browser the React app is always prioritized over other endpoints, even though it is at the end of the express chain.

I add the React build as static folder like so:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/react'), {
  etag: false
}));
```

Also tried to set `etag` to `false` so it wouldn't cache the app, but it still opens even when the server is down. I send the react build by using a wildcard `GET` request at the end of the express chain:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(global.appRoot, '/views/index.html'));
});
```

There are other endpoints before it, but non of them are accessed through the browser, it just skips to the React build. The endpoints are called fine if Postman is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it still opens when the server is down you have most likely a service-worker installed that is caching URLs with the index.html.

On Chrome, go to Applications tab of the Chrome Dev Tools and check if there are any service workers registered for the domain name you are using.

If there is you can unregister and then try again :)
But make sure that you check your service-worker, because if it is set to intercept all network requests with the html it will happen again.

Comment: Thanks! That worked and will help during the development but it's still not a solution for production.

Comment: What are you using? `create-react-app`? Service-workers are a tricky thing and it is very easy to misconfigure them. Do you really need them?

Comment: Yes, so can i just disable them for all users? And is it done in the back-end or front-end?

Comment: Upgrade your version of `react-scripts`. They have disabled the service-worker in a recent version for exactly this reason. Remove the service-worker in your browser, upgrade your `react-script` version, build and load again and see if it still installs a service-worker.